# While trying to automate facebook signup page through selenium webdriver the page is getting loaded in hindi as default? How to make it open in eng?

Tags: java, selenium

The same being opened in an brower without automating is opening in english.Using the below Code:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/r.php?locale=EN_US&campaign_id=973072070&extra_1=s%7Cc%7C256741383347%7Ce%7Cfacebook%20sign%20up%7C&placement=&creative=256741383347&keyword=facebook%20sign%20up&partner_id=googlesem&extra_2=campaignid%3D973072070%26adgroupid%3D54006292691%26matchtype%3De%26network%3Dg%26source%3Dnotmobile%26search_or_content%3Ds%26device%3Dc%26devicemodel%3D%26adposition%3D%26target%3D%26targetid%3Dkwd-295862466660%26loc_physical_ms%3D20464%26loc_interest_ms%3D%26feeditemid%3D19894516786%26param1%3D%26param2%3D&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIhae5qNH98AIVtdxMAh18Rw2UEAAYASABEgJvEvD_BwE");
    
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        WebElement day = driver.findElement(By.id("day"));
        WebElement month = driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
        WebElement year = driver.findElement(By.id("year"));
        Select select = new Select(day);
        select.selectByVisibleText("5");
        
        Select select1 = new Select(month);
        select.selectByVisibleText("April");
        
        Select select2 = new Select(year);
        select.selectByVisibleText("1995");
```

Comment: Why would you automate Facebook sign up?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the site is opening in Hindi, that doesn't happen for me. In any case, I guess you can just tell selenium to switch language by identifying and clicking the right language link. I assume you want English?

```
// code to open the page
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text() = 'English (US)']")).click()
//rest of your test
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your facebook link instead of "http://facebook.com" use "http://en-gb.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ChromeDriver locale with the following code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--lang=en-US");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: `--lang=es` is spanish, I forget what English is though

Comment: You are right :) It was copy-paste mistake